# Unable to get different Content-Types in request mapping using Spring Framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Here is my controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/actuator")
public class HealthController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/metrics", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ResponseBody
    public HealthModel getDump() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return new HealthModel();
        //return mapper.writeValueAsString(metrics.invoke());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/metrics", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getHealth() {
        return "HEALTHY";
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class HealthModel {

    @JsonProperty
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty
    private int id;

    public HealthModel(){
        this.status="WARN";
        this.id=2;
    }

}
```

Note I have mapped `/metrics` to return `json` or `plain-text` depending on the `Accept Header` in the request

When I make request at

`curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/myapp/actuator/metrics`

I get expected response in json
`{"status":"WARN","id":2}`.

However, when I try

`curl -v -H "Accept: text/plain" http://localhost:8080/myapp/actuator/metrics`

I get `HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable`.

---

### EDIT

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class AppMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Resource(name = "appObjectMapper")
    private ObjectMapper appObjectMapper;

    @Resource(name = "modelObjectMapper")
    private ObjectMapper modelObjectMapper;

 @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
       
        final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter inputConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        inputConverter.setObjectMapper(appObjectMapper);

        final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter outputConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        outputConverter.setObjectMapper(modelObjectMapper);

        converters.add(new JacksonDualMapperConverter(appObjectMapper, modelObjectMapper));

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show your web configuration (EnableWebMvc configuration class, etc)? Did you configure specific messageconverters or content negotiation manager?

Comment: @BrianClozel: I do have EnableWebMVc class where I configured message converters. I have it above, but It is supposed to convert only Json I suppose.please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're adding a custom MessageConverter `configureMessageConverters`, this turns off default converter registration ([see JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#configureMessageConverters-java.util.List-)).

So when content negotiation kicks in, you only have one message converter (the Jackson one) that only supports JSON media types and does not know how to handle `text/plain`.

You should add a [StringHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html) to the list in order to support `text/plain`.

```
converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
```

Comment: looks like I need to add dependency in pom for spring-messaging. After adding it in pom, I still do not see import option for StringMessageConverter. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging/4.0.0.RELEASE

Comment: pilot error! You need the HTTP variant of this StringHttpMessageConverter, included in spring-webmvc. No need to add spring-messaging unless you're using spring-websocket or messaging oriented features. Sorry about that! I just edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: worked nicely. Thank you. if you worked with spring-boot-actuator, I have few questions posted here and you are now 10K congrats!

Comment: Indeed 10K, thanks! I'll look at those questions, maybe I can help.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case anyone still gets the `Type mismatch: cannot convert from MediaType to String[]` error:

The solution is to use **`MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`**

instead of `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`

Regards

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, `@ResponseBody` indicates that  indicates that the return type should be written straight to the HTTP response body (and not placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name). So annotation should be there. On the second look, your produces annotation does not seem to be correct.
It should be `produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE` and not `produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN`.
I tried the following and it worked for me:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/metrics", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getHealth() {
        return "HEALTHY";
    }
```

You also might have to add [StringHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html).

Comment: what is the MediaType are you using? is it `org.springframework.http.MediaType`; or  `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;`. I am using the second one.   when I try to use the first one, I get compile error `cannot convert from MediaType to 
  String[]`

Comment: I am using org.springframework.http.MediaType. As I mentioned, I am using  MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE which is a string

Comment: I tried to use same as yours. I get compile error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from MediaType to String[]`

Comment: @brainstorm, I got the "type mismatch" error too, when trying to use consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN.  Switched to consumes = "text/plain" and it compiles ok.  Don't know if that helps your situation, but thought it worth mentioning....